# My own library is giving me "undefined reference to <function_name>

Tags: c, sdl, lib

I'm trying to make a static library for my games, made from SDL, just to simplify my game making process.

I am using Code::Blocks and gcc compiler, and C language.

I linked SDL at the library project, and started making some functions. Then I wrote a test project, and linked both SDL and my library to it. But when I try to execute it, it gives me undefined reference to the variables on my library and to the functions of SDL. My library's functions work, but they call SDL functions inside, and those are the ones that give me undefined reference error.

The `lib.h` file looks like this:

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

extern int awesomeInteger;

extern void foo();
```

The `lib.c` looks like this:

```
#include "lib.h"

int awesomeInteger = 5;

void foo() {
   awesomeInteger = 6;
   SDL_Function();
}
```

And finally, the actual game code looks like this:

```
#include "lib.h"
// the lib.a file is already linked

int main() {
   foo();
}
```

And then there is an undefined reference error to `SDL_Function()`...

The log looks like this:

```
||=== Build: Debug in ExampleProject (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
/usr/bin/ld: obj/Debug/lib.o||in function `foo':|
/home/username/Documents/Dev/ExampleProject/lib.c|10|undefined reference to `SDL_Function'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Did you do a make install of the libsdl ?

Comment: No, is that necessary?

Comment: How does your link command look like?

Comment: Well, I am using Code::Blocks, so there's not anything like that... At least I didn't mess around with it.

Comment: But there's a linker thing, and I added the path to both my library and SDL library. Also the SDL dependency thing, which is something like -lSDL2

Comment: @snow any way to get a full build log?

Comment: It was too big, so here's a part of it:

||=== Build: Debug in HelloWorld (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
/usr/bin/ld: /home/gnevesdev/Documents/Dev/HelloWorld/deps/SSGL/lib/libSSGL.a(ssgl.o)||in function `SSGL_CriarJanela':|
/home/gnevesdev/Documents/Dev/SSGL/src/ssgl.c|10|undefined reference to `SDL_Init'|
/usr/bin/ld: /home/gnevesdev/Documents/Dev/SSGL/src/ssgl.c|13|undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'|||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 12 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: Edit your question to include full log, preferably with actual commands it executes, if your IDE is capable of that. What you have in comment doesn't reflect example in question. Please use the same code, as we usually can't read your mind.

Comment: Ok, I'm editing the question to include the full log using the code example

Comment: Try configuring your project to build a shared library instead of a static one.  These two types do not mix very well -- it is fairly likely that your static library's functions will not be able to use functions from SDL dynamic libraries, and it would not be unusual if your system had only dynamic SDL libraries, not static ones.

Comment: In 2020, there are few reasons to build static libraries (at least on Linux). See [Program Library HowTo](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details of your compilation and linking, and logs thereof, here is a reference for a manual build:

1. Create your static library (compile-only no link, you will later on link the necessary libraries into your actual executable)

`gcc mylib.c -c`

2. [Optional] If you have multiple object files you can create an archive (a collection of object files)

`ar rcs libmylib.a obj1.o obj2.o`

3. Add the library to your program by including the object files in the build, and link with SDL.

`gcc -lSDL2 mygame.c libmylib.a`

Comment: I don't follow why you think this answers the question.  The OP claims that they are successfully building the static library, and that they are including both that and the appropriate SDL libraries when they attempt to link programs.  What, then, are you saying they are doing wrong, or have failed to do?

Comment: Fair point, but it serves as a guideline for a manual build process eliminating any funky business introduced by the code::blocks build automation, for example. Edit, and I felt like it was too long of a post for a comment.

Comment: Ok, but *that does not answer the question*.

Comment: I edited the post to reflect that it is simply a reference guide.